# using html text in as3

Tags: actionscript-3

i'm having a bit of a question, I have some newspost from my database. But there are  tags in it and some  tags aswell. My questiion is how i should go about it to get the newspost showing as it should be. The images should get shown instead of the  tags etc. I know i'll have to work with a loader to use the images but how would as3 recognize them? Is there anyway i could use htmltext or something so as3 knows automaticly where the imagetags are?

Also, if i add the image would it be possible to wrap the text around it? So i dont have an empty space next to the image?

Answer (score 1):

[looks possible (list of supported html tags)](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#htmlText)

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick Google search and found this, maybe it can help you:

http://www.railodeveloper.com/post.cfm/flash-as3-images-in-htmltext-how-to